# api2.0p5 No BuildHeader or BuildContent for cardbard.card

Tags: rally

All,

In messing with the new cards found in 2.0p5, I noticed there is no longer a template available to alter the header or the content of the actual card.

Can someone confirm this is not available, just want to make sure I am not missing it anywhere...

There really is no way to alter the display of the card?

Just for clarity of the post, in 2.0p2 you could do a buildContent function or buildHeader function inside Ext.define of the Card.

Comment: The header and card content are rendered using plugin classes. These plugin classes may be configured to display different content. If you can explain what you want to display, I can give you a description of how to do it.

Comment: Well... In my "old board" I had customized quite a bit, one of the bigger items was a button for who takes the story for code review.  So if story is in a certain column, and a specific field is emtpy, a button appears.  If the column is full it means someone is reviewing it.  Also things like showing all the defects tied to a story, and where that defect is (in dev, in qa, etc).  I notice on the new Rally App for Iteration Tracking Board.  Those cards show more than the default cardboard.Card class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The card no longer has a template that you can modify directly, however you can create a custom CardContent plugin to display custom html:

```
Ext.define('Rally.ui.cardboard.plugin.MyCardContent', {
    alias: 'plugin.rallymycardcontent',
    extend: 'Rally.ui.cardboard.plugin.CardContent',
    getHtml: function() {
        var html = this.callParent(arguments);
        return html + '<span>mycontent</span>';
    }
});
```

Then configure your CardBoard to use the custom plugin:

```
Ext.create('Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard', {
    types: ['User Story', 'Defect'],
    attribute: "ScheduleState",
    fieldNames: ['Tasks'], // display task information inline on card
    cardConfig: {
        // overriding plugins to add the custom plugin
        // be sure to include the default plugins.
        plugins: [
            {ptype: 'rallycardheader'},
            {ptype: 'rallymycardcontent'},
            {ptype: 'rallycardpopover'}
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great first step, I appreciate the help!!

Comment: One question on your code you posted, you show a fieldNames for Tasks, is this supposed to show the actual icon etc on the card like the default kanban board does?  I get Tasks in dropdown menu from the card, but not on the card itself.

Comment: It should display in the card if the User Story has a task, but I'm not sure if that feature is in 2.0p5, or in our development branch, I'll have to check.